# Reading the name of a file given as InputStream

Tags: java

I am currently writing a code were I need to read the name of a given file and create a new file changing a only the extension.
The way I input the file is of the form

```
java myProgram < fileName
```

How can I get the fileName and convert it into a String using Java, I tried with a Scanner and a BufferedReader but it only allows me to read inside the file but not the fileName?

Comment: To read it, you already a filename right ? You are inputting something and you want to know that ? Confused.

Comment: I want to retrieve the name of the file that I input in the program but not read the content of the file

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with your command line, because you pass the *content* of the file directly on the standard input.

You should consider passing the filename as parameter of your main class.
You command line will be something like that :

```
java myProgram fileName
```

In your main method, you have a String arrays as parameter, the filename will be into it, at the first position (index 0).

After, use this filename to read the file into your code

Comment: The issue I have with this is that in an another part of my program I need to read what is inside the given file, that's why I have the file given to program using `java myProgram < fileName` and not `java myProgram fileName`, I guess the only way to do both is to use `java myProgram fileName < fileName` but I feel that it is redundant

Comment: If you have the filename, you can read the file without need to pass it on standard input. You can read all lines of a file, for example, by using the File APi as follow: `Files.newReader( File file, Charset charset).lines();`

Comment: I know but I am using some auto-generated files that use the InputStream given by the `System.in`, that's why I need the my command line to use `< fileName`

Comment: So, no more solution: rewrite the autogenerated code not to use System.in and read the file with File Java API, or duplicate the filename on the command line

Answer (score 0):

`java myProgram < fileName` change this to `java myProgram  fileName` , fileName will be assigned as an element to `String[] args`.